# What is the formula for this probability problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations

I have a set of characters. They have spaces as well and these can move in between the characters. Say a set of characters are `abc--` then the spaces can be moved as follow `a-b-c`. Keep in mind that the characters can never break their order that is for a set of characters `abc--` can never be arranged as `b-c-a` but `a-b-c` is fine.

I want to calculate all the propability a set of characters and spaces can have.

Example

```
a b d - -
```

can be

```
a b d - -
a b - d -
a - b d -
- a b d -
- a b - d
- a - b d
- - a b d
a b - - d
a - - b d
a - b - d
```

If I am not wrong this example has 10 different probabilities.

I need a formula that can calculate the propability the spaces can move between characters without the characters breaking their order

i.e:

```
a b c d e - - - - -

a b c d -
```

Can you healp me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $n$ characters, and $m$ spaces.  You are then counting solutions to $$a_0+a_1+\cdots +a_n=m$$
in nonnegative integers.  $a_0$ represents the number of spaces following $0$ letters, $a_1$ represents the number of spaces following $1$ letter, etc.

This is counted with [Multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), specifically as $$\left(\!\!{n+1\choose m}\!\!\right)={m+n\choose m}=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$$

For the test case, $n=3, m=2$, giving $\frac{5!}{2!3!}=\frac{120}{2\cdot 6}=10$.